# Next-Auth providers with a Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, next.js, next-auth

I've been trying to implement Next-Auth with Typescript and an OAuth provider, such as Auth0. After following the docs the problem appeared, and even after watching tons of videos and doing *exactly* what other people did, the error persists. Here is the code snippet for the `api/auth/[...nextauth.tsx]`:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import Auth0 from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Auth0({
            clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET,
            domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        }),
    ],
});
```

The error I'm getting is in both `clientId` and `clientSecret`, and is described below:
[image]

What I don't understand, however, is that when looking at `oauth.d.ts` I find that both accept either `string` or `undefined`:
[image]

I'd really appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you actually look at the declaration, it is as such:

```
export type OAuthUserConfig<P>
Alias for:
Omit<Partial<OAuthConfig<P>>, "options" | "type"> & Required<Pick<OAuthConfig<P>, "clientId" | "clientSecret">>
```

The reason behind this I believe is that without the `clientId` and `clientSecret` the OAuth will never work properly.

Two possible ways of fixing it:

- the very lazy (and not so good) way would be to simply cast it as a string

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import Auth0 from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Auth0({
            clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET as string,
            domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        }),
    ],
});
```

- a bit less lazy, and you can add yourself manual warnings if the values are empty

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import Auth0 from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

const { AUTH0_ID = '', AUTH0_SECRET = '', AUTH0_DOMAIN = '' } = process.env;

// potential console.error here to warn yourself you forgot to set the env values

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Auth0({
          clientId: AUTH0_ID,
          clientSecret: AUTH0_SECRET,
          domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As in the [NextAuth.js typescript example](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example), you could create a [process.d.ts](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/process.d.ts) file that contains the following:

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    AUTH0_ID: string
    AUTH0_SECRET: string
    AUTH0-DOMAIN: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by putting a ternary validation on the clientId and clientSecret variable assignment, like this:

```
clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ID ? process.env.AUTH0_ID : ""
clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET ? process.env.AUTH0_SECRET : ""
```

and it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can use a non-null assertion operator (!) to assert that the environment variables will always have a value. However, it's important to ensure that the variables are properly set in your environment configuration to avoid potential runtime errors.
This is because the error you are experiencing indicates that there is an issue with the types of the environment variables process.env.AUTH0_ID, and process.env.AUTH0_SECRET. The error specifically mentions that string | undefined is not assignable to type string

Fix:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```